# Several setTimeout() functions

Tags: javascript

In chrome console the code

```
setTimeout( () => element.click(), 1000)
```

works well. But with several timeouts

```
setTimeout( () => element1.click(), 1000)
setTimeout( () => element2.click(), 1000)
```

only the first one will produce a delay. 
What should I do to produce several pauses?

Comment: You need to nest your timeouts if you want another pause to only start when the previous one finishes.

Comment: In the second example both `click` methods will be called at the same time

Comment: I'm sorry. It's a typo. There should be click() functuion

Comment: Yes. And I need to call them one by one.